# How to rar/unrar with command line parameters

Tags: c#, winrar

I've looked through the internet on how winrar's command line parameters work, and this is what I have so far

```
        void LOCK(string fld, string pw)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "rar a -p" + pw + " PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar " + fld;
        p.Start();
    }

    void UNLOCK(string fld, string pw)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "unrar x -p" + pw + " PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar";
        p.Start();
    }
```

However it doesn't seem to create any archive anywhere, with a test folder being C:\PicsAndStuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StartInfo` you define results in running `WinRAR.exe` with command line:

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe unrar x -p pw PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar
```

That is of course wrong as you do not want to run `WinRAR.exe` with first argument being a reference to console version `Rar.exe` or `UnRAR.exe`. The result is most likely an error message because of invalid command `rar` respectively `unrar` as the first argument must be `a` or `x` for `WinRAR.exe`.

So first of all you need to correct `StartInfo`:

```
void LOCK(string fld, string pw)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "a -p" + pw + " PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar " + fld;
    p.Start();
}

void UNLOCK(string fld, string pw)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "x -p" + pw + " PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar";
    p.Start();
}
```

Further all commands and switches of console version `Rar.exe` are briefly explained when simply running `Rar.exe` without any parameter in a command prompt window. Also `UnRAR.exe` outputs a brief help if executed without any parameter.

Last but not least there is a complete manual for `Rar.exe` which of course can also extract files and folders from a RAR archive which makes additional usage of `UnRAR.exe` useless. The manual is text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of `WinRAR` which you should read from top to bottom. I suggest to build the command line while reading it and test the command line first from within a command prompt window.

**Note 1:**
`Rar.exe` is shareware. Only `UnRAR.exe` is freeware.

**Note 2:**
GUI version `WinRAR.exe` supports more than console version `Rar.exe` and therefore the list of switches differ slightly. Complete documentation for `WinRAR.exe` can be found in help of *WinRAR* opened with **Help - Help Topics** or pressing key <kbd>F1</kbd>. Open in help on tab **Contents** the item *Command line mode* and read. `WinRAR.exe` is also shareware.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encrypt both file data and headers.

According to [Documentation](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/) ***(Command line mode > Switches > "-hp[pwd] - encrypt both file data and headers")***:

> This switch is similar to -p[p], but switch -p encrypts only file data
>   and leaves other information like file names visible. This switch
>   encrypts all sensitive archive areas including file data, file names,
>   sizes, attributes, comments and other blocks, so it provides a higher
>   security level.

This is how you can access to it using command line:

**Syntax**: rar a -hp[MyPassword] -r [filepath] [folderpath]

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -hp12345678 -r d:\zipProject d:\Project
```

**C# Code:**

```
void LOCK(string fld, string pw)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "rar a -hp" + pw + " PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar " + fld;
    p.Start();
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the rar file isn't being created, not that the file names aren't encrypted

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect, even if I do `p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"rar a -hp" + pw + @" C:\Users\Elmeri\PL_LOCKED_ARCHIVE.rar " + fld;` it does not create a rar in C:\Users\Elmeri